# Selenium no such element found

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I try to take the href from an element using RSelenium.

Here is an example of html structure:

```
<ol id="rem">
<div class="bare">
   <h3>
      <a class="tlt mhead" href="https://www.myexample.com">
```

I use this:

```
pro<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/input[@class = 'bare']")
  pro$highlightElement()
```

but it can't find the element and returns this error:

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the `input` element has the `bare` class, the `div` (assuming `dib` is a typo):

```
//div[@class='bare']/h3/a
```

Comment: thank you. Yes it is div and not dib. It seems very logical but unfortunately again I receive the same error. Even if I tried this `pro<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/div[@class='bare']/h3/a")` which could have different syntax in RSelenium

Comment: could be a problem because there is a list in dom with this structure? So I could give the position i.e. [1]